# Iterate through a file until match and find a second, different match, until no match. Repeat until EOF

Tags: bash, if-statement, recursion, grep, xargs

Hi I have a fairly large but messy output from a salt script I'm running.

Basically my cleanest output looks like this:

```
MINION:server1.xyz.com
MINION:server2.xyz.com
MINION:server3.xyz.com
filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath2
filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath3
filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath4
MINION:server4.xyz.com
filer4:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server5.xyz.com
MINION:server6.xyz.com
MINION:server7.xyz.com
filer3:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
```

What I want is ONLY to return the minions that have filers beneath them and all of the filers beneath them and I'd like to get it formatted as such:

```
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1 
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath2
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath3
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath4
MINION:server4.xyz.com filer4:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server7.xyz.com filer3:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
```

I've looked into if statements, recursive statements, etc.  I either am failing to understand bash recursive statements or thats not what I want to do.  I'm hoping to find an efficient way of doing this without scanning the file more than once.

Is there a tricky way to use xargs?  Is there something in grep that can do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '/^MINION:/{m=$0} /^filer/{print m, $0}' file
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath2
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath3
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath4
MINION:server4.xyz.com filer4:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server7.xyz.com filer3:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
```

Comment: Is it granted that a "filer" line is always immediately preceded by a MINION line (or other "filer" lines)?  If that is the case, anubhava's script is quite elegant - otherwise it will fail at those other cases - although that would also be easy to fix in awk.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann: This awk will still work if there are some random lines between `MINION` and `filer` lines

Comment: That works!

Can you explain what is going on here?  I never seem to get to the end of awk's abilities...

Comment: `/^MINION:/{m=$0}` stores current line in variable `m` if line starts with `MINION`. Then `/^filer/{print m, $0}` prints `m` and current line when that line starts with `filer`

Comment: @anubhava: Unless the first line is a "filer" line :-)

Comment: How do i allow for something that "xyzfiler" instead of just "filer"?

Comment: Somehow this worked: awk '/^MINION:/{m=$0} m && /^[filer|denfiler]/{print m, $0}'

Comment: That will work, you can also try: `awk '/^MINION:/{m=$0} m && /filer/{print m, $0}' file`

Answer (score 2):

A Bash only solution would be:

```
minions_with_filers () 
{ 
    label=;
    while IFS=: read -r a b; do
        case $a in 
            MINION)
                label=$a:$b
            ;;
            filer[0-9]*)
                printf '%s %s:%s\n' "$label" "$a" "$b"
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Though, **@anubhava**'s solution will run ~10 times faster.

*Usage example:*

```
$ minions_with_filers < foo.txt 
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath2
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath3
MINION:server3.xyz.com filer1:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath4
MINION:server4.xyz.com filer4:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
MINION:server7.xyz.com filer3:/vol/storagestuffs/volpath1
```